# How to trigger a same followup event for every Intent without webhook in API.AI?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am creating a bot using Api.Ai. I have a set of 30 intents with the responses. I want Dialog flow to ask the user a follow-up question every time user ask something  "Are you fine with the answers". Basically, a follow up for each question user ask, the bot will reply with the answer and follow up question.

Scenario:

```
User: What is the Maternity insurance plan? (No action here)
Bot: Reply with some Response from Text Response.
Bot: Are you satisfied with the answer?
User: YES/NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Without webhook, it will be messy and may invoke the follow-up intent every now and then or trigger unwanted intents. Better to put YES/NO follow-up for every intent you want or use webhook and handle this programmatically. 
Still, if you want to do it using Dialogflow only, then you can do it like this:

1. Create a separate new intent for Yes and separate intent for No, and put all the respective synonyms in the User Says for training.
2. Add an input context "`are-you-satisfied`" (or other of your choice) to the YES intent and the NO intent. No other context should be put in the input context.
3. In the intents where you are asking for the question "Are you satisfied with the answer?", add an output context as "`are-you-satisfied`" with a lifespan of 2 or 3.
4. Keep the other contexts in the output context as per requirement with the use case.

With this what happens is, you will have 2 intents with input context "`are-you-satisfied`" and invoked with either YES or NO. There will be no follow-up intent as such. These two will act as a follow-up whenever the input context is present in the output context and YES or NO is said.

But as I said earlier, it may get messy when there are other contexts active which are ready to fire after YES or NO is said. In that case, it may trigger a different intent based on the active context and may not be liked by the user.

**UPDATE**
If you are using webhook you can do it like this:

1. You can use [helpers](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers)  "`ask.for.permission.confirmation`" and check for
    
   `if (confirmationGranted) { ... }` in the individual intent's webhook handler method.
   OR
2. Create the two YES/NO intents as above, put the input context and output context as above to respective intents.
3. Create two webhook handler functions for YES and NO.
4. When these intents are triggered, check what is the active context and proceed accordingly like

   `switch (activeContext){
      case context1: ....
      case context2: ....
   }`
5. You may need to manipulate context's lifespan so as to not trigger a wrong intent afterward.

My choice would be to go with helper methods or individually having YES or NO follow-up intents.

Comment: How to do it using Webhook then, Because if I use "followupEventInput", it will directly trigger the feedback intent, without showing the text response for that particular question.